# "Timeout Obtaining a Connection from the Pool"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can any one help to get rid of this error

"Time Out expired.The time out elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool .This have occurred because all pooled connections were in  use and max pool size was reached"

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're implementing using blocks for every object that you create that implements IDisposable:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) {
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                // do something with row
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you will leak resources (including connections) when an exception occurs.

BTW, in VB, that's

```
Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString))
...
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

This generally occurs when trying to connect to a database after exhausting all available connections. This article on [Tuning Up ADO.NET Connection Pooling in ASP.NET Applications](http://forums.asp.net/t/1405451.aspx) should explain how to fix the issue you are having. That said things to try: close all SqlConnections, dispose of all Sqldatasources, and increase the max pool size.

Answer (score 1):

did you remember to close each of the database connections after you used them?

Answer (score -1):

In your connection string, make sure you set **pooling=false**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add 
name="YourConnectionString"
connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=your_db;Uid=username; _
Pwd=password;pooling=false;" <---------------POOLING = FALSE
providerName="yourprovider"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: But what if connection pooling is required?

Comment: recommending do not use pooling is a bad advice.